# C# odd list behavior

Tags: c#, list, pointers

This may be somewhat of a noobish question but I cannot seem to find any information on this behavior at all.

Here is the code:

```
class Cars
{
    public int year = 0;
    public string make = " ";
    public string model = " ";

    public Cars()
    {
    }

    public Cars(int tYear, string tMake, string tModel)
    {
        year = tYear;
        make = tMake;
        model = tModel;
    }

    public string ConvertToString()
    {
        return year.ToString() + make + model;
    }
}

class Program
{
    Cars oneCar = new Cars();
    List<Cars> manyCars = new List<Cars>();

    public void Init()
    {
        manyCars.Add(new Cars(1993, "Nissan", "240SX"));
        manyCars.Add(new Cars(2001, "Isuzu", "Rodeo"));
        manyCars.Add(new Cars(2010, "Ford", "F150"));

        oneCar = manyCars[2];
        oneCar.model = "Pinto";

        for (int i = 0; i < manyCars.Count(); i++)
            Console.WriteLine(manyCars[i].ConvertToString());

        Console.WriteLine(oneCar.ConvertToString());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prg1 = new Program();
        prg1.Init();
    }
}
```

The output is this:

> 1993Nissan240SX
>
> 2001IsuzuRodeo
>
> 2010FordPinto
>
> 2010FordPinto

Why is the third line reading Pinto instead of F150?  It seems to be setting the oneCar variable to be a pointer or something.  How can this be avoided?  I thought that's what the "new" keyword accomplished.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html

Comment: You would need to clone manyCars[2] and then make changes to the cloned object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Cars` is an object, and objects are `Reference Types` in C#.

When you call this line of code:

```
oneCar = manyCars[2];
```

You are pointing `oneCar` to the memory location of `manyCars[2]`. They are referencing the same object. Updating `oneCar` also updates `manyCars[2]`.

[This link](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) has a good writeup on Reference and Value types.

Comment: Thanks a ton, answered my question exactly.  Was not aware that reference/value types were handled differently.

Answer (score 3):

`manyCars[2]` is the Ford. So after the assignement `oneCar` is the same Ford. But remember that class types are reference types. This means that `oneCar` and `manyCars[2]` point to the same car object! Therefore setting `oneCar.model = "Pinto"` has the same effect than setting `manyCars[2].model = "Pinto"`.

`oneCar = manyCars[2];` does not create a copy of the objects content. You could add a `Clone` method to the cars class

```
public Cars Clone()
{
    return (Cars)MemberwiseClone(); // This method is inherited from object.
}
```

Then this really creates a copy

```
oneCar = manyCars[2].Clone();
```

Now `oneCar` and `manyCars[2]` are two distinct objects and changing `oneCar's` model won't affect the model of `manyCars[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

In c# there are value and reference types - a class is a reference type. Your code above adds three new car objects to the ManyCars list - then sets the OneCar variable to a reference of the 3rd list element - in your case to the F150. You then overwrite the model property with Pinto and then iterate through your list.

You've basically set OneCar to be a pointer to the original Car object. If you want to make a copy of the object that you can then change without affecting the original in the List you need to Clone the Car object not just assign it to the OneCar variable.

Cheers
Simon